# Html 5 plachold text with plugin - How to remove the focus from textbox

Tags: jquery, html

I have implemented the IE8 support placehold plugin, its enabled in the text box but first time there is focus set it up so text is showing there when first loads the page. If i click outside of text page, the message is showing.

I'm following http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/form-placeholder-text/ plugin and in the text box every thing looks good.

```
// A jQuery based placeholder polyfill
$(document).ready(function(){
  function add() {
    if($(this).val() === ''){
      $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder')).addClass('placeholder');
    }
  }

  function remove() {
    if($(this).val() === $(this).attr('placeholder')){
      $(this).val('').removeClass('placeholder');
    }
  }

  // Create a dummy element for feature detection
  if (!('placeholder' in $('<input>')[0])) {

    // Select the elements that have a placeholder attribute
    $('input[placeholder], textarea[placeholder]').blur(add).focus(remove).each(add);

    // Remove the placeholder text before the form is submitted
    $('form').submit(function(){
      $(this).find('input[placeholder], textarea[placeholder]').each(remove);
    });
  }
});
```

Please see the below [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rwPFx/53/embedded/result/)

Comment: How is the focus set, by JavaScript/jQuery, or with the [`autofocus` attribute](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML5_form_additions#autofocus)?